# Why do we include the target class in both the arrays in train_test_split?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

```
X_train, test_df, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(result, y_true, stratify = y_true, test_size = 0.2)
```

In the above sample use of train_test_split, `result` is the data frame and `y_true` is a numpy array formed from the target class column from the data frame.

My question is why we do we give the whole 'result' data frame as one of the input parameters in train_test_split if we are already giving 'y_true' separately? I mean, shouldn't we first exclude the target class column from the 'result' data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn has pandas support, but pandas is not a requirement. With numpy arrays it doesn't always make sense to have both your features and labels in the same array, hence the current design of the `train_test_split` function. So it's up to you to make sure that your `result` DataFrame and its splits have the format you desire. If `y_true` is part of your `result` DataFrame, you can (and should) choose to exclude it before or after the function call.